# How can I avoid jumpy transition of a View with DatePicker on devices with a bottom safe area?

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

In my app, I have a screen with that shows a list of events. There is a `View` that slides up from the bottom, over the list, so the user can quickly add additional events with a `DatePicker` while still seeing the list.

[image: list view with panel]

I've encountered strange behavior: on devices without a bottom safe area, like the iPhone SE or iPhone 7 Plus, the sliding up animation of the `View` that contains the `DatePicker` is smooth.

However, on devices with a bottom safe area, like the iPhone 14 or iPhone 12, the animation is jumpy. While it is animating up, it seems to have a hiccup along the way.

I first noticed that this issue is fully reproducible on real devices, but also seems to be visible in simulators.

When I remove the `DatePicker`, the animation is smooth.

**What can I do to make this animation smooth on devices with a bottom safe area?**

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var panelPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("Dummy Data \(index)")
                    }
                }
                    .navigationBarTitle("List View")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        panelPresented.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                })

                if panelPresented {
                    PanelView(isPresented: $panelPresented)
                        .transition(AnyTransition
                        .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom),
                                    removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
                        .zIndex(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PanelView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    @GestureState private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var panelVerticalOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var panelHeight: CGFloat = 0

    private let dismissVelocityThreshold: CGFloat = 100

    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Toolbar(isPresented: $isPresented)

                VStack {
                    Text("This is a panel where the user can quickly add events with a DatePicker.")
                        .padding()

                    Button {
                        //
                    } label: {
                        Text("Button")
                            .padding()
                    }
                        .buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())

                    DatePicker("Pick date",
                               selection: $selectedDate)
                        .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                        .labelsHidden()
                }
            }
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                .background(Color.white
                .shadow(color: Color.secondary.opacity(0.5),
                        radius: 8,
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0)
            )
        }
            .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: PanelHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
        })
            .onPreferenceChange(PanelHeightPreferenceKey.self) { newValue in
            panelHeight = newValue
        }
            .offset(y: isPresented ? (panelVerticalOffset + dragOffset) : panelHeight)
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: panelVerticalOffset)
            .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .local)
                .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
                if value.translation.height >= 0 {
                    state = value.translation.height
                } else {
                    state = 0
                }
            }
                .onEnded { value in
                let predictedTranslationHeight = value.predictedEndLocation.y - value.location.y

                if predictedTranslationHeight > dismissVelocityThreshold {
                    withAnimation {
                        isPresented = false
                    }
                } else {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        panelVerticalOffset = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        )
            .onChange(of: isPresented) { newValue in
            if newValue {
                panelVerticalOffset = 0
            }
        }
    }

    struct Toolbar: View {
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool

        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Text("Data Entry Panel")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        // Hide the panel
                        isPresented = false
                    } label: {
                        Text("Done")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                        .padding(.trailing)
                }
            }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
        }
    }

    struct PanelHeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        typealias Value = CGFloat

        static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0

        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = nextValue()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** Based on the suggestion from Yrb in the comments, I updated the code so that `PanelView` is not created and destroyed each time by using an `.offset` modifier instead of the conditional.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var panelPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("Dummy Data \(index)")
                    }
                }
                    .navigationBarTitle("List View")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                        panelPresented.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                })


                PanelView(isPresented: $panelPresented)
                    .transition(AnyTransition
                    .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom),
                                removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
                    .zIndex(1)
                    .offset(y: panelPresented ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, even after this change, so that the view lifecycle of the `PanelView` is the same as the `ContentView`, **the jumpiness in the animation still exists** when the panel is sliding up and down when there is a `DatePicker` inside the panel.

Comment: 2 things. 1. Remove the `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))`. The version of `.animation()` is deprecated with good reason. It is also redundant in that you animate the variable that causes the view to appear in the first place. 2. Either use a native sheet (recommended), or have the view you are moving in exist the entire time by removing the if statement, and just offset it off the screen. The issue you are having is an animation timing issue, similar to when an animation is started in `.onAppear()`. Also, watch [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).

Comment: @Yrb Thank you, I will re-watch that WWDC video you linked. 1) I know that `.animation` is deprecated, however when I remove it the panel stops behaving the way I want it to: when a user drags it down and lets go, it immediately appears at the top of its position instead of animating back up to the top of its position. I have not been able to find another solution to maintain this behavior, so I kept the deprecated function.

Comment: @Yrb 2) I am not using sheet since I want the user to still be able to see the list while interacting with the panel (instead of covering the whole list). When I make the `PanelView` exist the entire time, I run into a lot of extra complexity and `@State var`s in the `PanelView`, since I can't do setup & teardown operations for the view in its .onAppear and .onDisappear functions.

Comment: If you need the `.animation()` you need to key it to a variable. It will give you wonky results in the long run. As to the setup and teardown problem in the view, you should not have views that complex. They should be lightweight. If you have that much to do, consider moving it to a ViewModel.

Comment: @Yrb I have tried keying `.animation()` to a variable, but it ends up breaking the current UI behavior. Could you propose an answer that keys it to a variable without changing the UI behavior? I have not been able to find a solution that behaves this way without using the deprecated version of `.animation()`.

Comment: @Yrb Also, I took your advice to make `PanelView` exist the entire time instead of being created and destroyed with the conditional, however it still has the buggy animation behavior whenever a `DatePicker` is present on a device that has bottom safe area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same issue with a custom bottom sheet that uses the same ZStack mechanism.
I managed to fix the "jump" during the animation by adding the `.compositingGroup()` modifier to the `DatePicker`.

I am not sure about the technical implications, but I haven't noticed anything weird and the picker is fully functional.